# Can't I add paper sizes to MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, paper

I do a lot of work with  A5 size pages and I hate always going to Custom, and often having to re-enter the dimensions. I'd like to add A5 to the standard list of paper sizes, or at least to the standard list of custom sizes.

Comment: If you go to page layout and then to size you get a dropdown including A5, in Word 2007. Then you can just set it at the default style

Comment: Not on my Word 2013. @Techie007 says below it depends on the printer driver.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I couldn't find documentation on the microsoft site; the best I can do is the word of a [word MVP here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/re-create-custom-built-paper-size-t4041153.html)

Comment: Here is a [MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/904805) about word overriding printer driver settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of page sizes presented in Word are the page sizes presented to the OS by your printer driver.

If you haven't already, go get the latest driver for your printer from the printer's manufacturer and see if it adds A5 for you.

If updating the driver doesn't just add it automatically, then you'll either need to manually add the A5 size to your printer driver as a custom size (may or may not be possible, depending on the printer driver in use), or get a printer driver/printer that properly reports it supports A5 to the OS.